# Can't make virtual host working

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost, nameserver

I have to create a virtual host on a server which, previously hosted a single website (domain name). Now I'm trying to add a second domain on this server (using the same nameserver). What I've done so far:

Initially there was no virtual host so I've made one for the second domain:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/bla
        ServerName www.blabla.com
        ServerAlias blabla.com
    <Directory /var/www/blabla>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

Because nothing happend, I changed the DocumentRoot of the apache server to */var/www* (initially was the root document of the first website -*/var/www/html*) and created a virtual host for the first domain too:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html
            ServerName www.first.com
            ServerAlias first.com
        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost *:80>
```

In this case, first.com is working ok, but bla.com not.
When I ping blabla.com I get the "unkown host" response. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to modify something in the DNS settings too? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if ping isn't resolving the name, then you'll need to configure DNS for that domain (or a hosts file locally, if you're just trying to test) to point to your Apache server.

Comment: Thanks! But, why do this happen? I updated the nameservers and they are appearing with whois. Why ping is not resolving the name?

Comment: @sica07 Can you clarify what's pointed where?  The name servers specified in whois are the DNS servers that you're telling the TLD to delegate to for your domain.  The entries that you put in there should be DNS servers that are configured to be authoritative for your domain; those systems will be the ones getting the DNS requests for a name of `blabla.com` or `www.blabla.com` and sending back a response with the address of your server.  Are the servers you're pointing to in the whois entry authoritative DNS servers configured to host your domain?

Comment: Well, the only configuration I've done so far, was to add the Virtual Host. I thought (and read in some tutorials) that it is enough. Could you please help me with a link to some info about how to configure the DNS also?

Comment: @sica07 Let's back up a sec - do you know where your authoritative DNS is hosted now for `first.com`?  It may be on this system, or it may be a provider's system.  That system is where you'd need to point the delegations in the whois registration, and it's where you'll need to configure the `blabla.com` zone.

Comment: I've done that already. It's on this system, I'm absolutely sure. And in the whois registration I pointed the delegations to this system, also, I made the Virtual Host configs on this system. I just have read in the apache docs, as you already said, that: "You must first have your DNS server properly configured to map those names to an IP address associated with your server." This is one thing I didn't do (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @sica07 Well, you'd be the one to ask on how you configured it originally ;)  Assuming that it's BIND, you'll want to find the config file and zone files, configure a `zone` of type `master` for the new domain name in the conf file, and point it to a zone file with proper `SOA` and `NS` entries (look at your existing zone for a template), as well as `A` records to point client web browsers at the server.

Comment: I thought about that, but can I create a new master zone and still use the nameservers from the first site(first master zone)?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow.  You'll be using the same BIND process, so it's the same name server.. but it's a new master zone, and needs to be a separate `zone` statement in the config.

Comment: Yes, it is. I was talking about the nameservers, and yes it's working. I will not try to explain what I was thinking of because I created a new zone as you said, and it's working! Thank you VERY much! You helped me a lot!!!!